# react-native-reanimated module causing Android app to crash on launch

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-stack, react-native-reanimated

I'm building a react native app using Expo managed workflow that is working perfectly when I test it in the Expo Go app. When I then tried further testing it in a standalone app by creating an APK file, loading it to an Android, and opening it up it immediately crashed.

From reading through the error logs (see key excerpt below) it seems like the operative issue is the react-native-reanimated module, which I did not proactively install but seems to be a dependency of @react-navigation/stack indirectly.

I've tried the following:

- Actively install the latest version of react-native-reanimated using npx expo install
- Ensure the dependent modules of @react-navigation/stack (react-native-screens and react-native-gesture-handling) are using the proper version of react-native-reanimated

Anyone have an idea of what to do?

```
08-29 02:13:46.129 15060 15060 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000076c58  /data/app/~~UGWiDx2QfyqHzMzDz3yeJA==/com.orderly.ios-8kJ1mW4XV4HiJGnvR0RZ1A==/lib/arm64/libreanimated.so (BuildId: 49e1dad0ba9bb0991bf54ebcc3a00d351229d18e)
08-29 02:13:46.129 15060 15060 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 000000000008d154  /data/app/~~UGWiDx2QfyqHzMzDz3yeJA==/com.orderly.ios-8kJ1mW4XV4HiJGnvR0RZ1A==/lib/arm64/libreanimated.so (reanimated::Scheduler::triggerUI()+176) (BuildId: 49e1dad0ba9bb0991bf54ebcc3a00d351229d18e)
08-29 02:13:46.129 15060 15060 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0000000000090a0c  /data/app/~~UGWiDx2QfyqHzMzDz3yeJA==/com.orderly.ios-8kJ1mW4XV4HiJGnvR0RZ1A==/lib/arm64/libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (reanimated::AndroidScheduler::*)(), &(reanimated::AndroidScheduler::triggerUI()), reanimated::AndroidScheduler, void>::dispatch(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>)+44) (BuildId: 49e1dad0ba9bb0991bf54ebcc3a00d351229d18e)
08-29 02:13:46.129 15060 15060 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 0000000000090978  /data/app/~~UGWiDx2QfyqHzMzDz3yeJA==/com.orderly.ios-8kJ1mW4XV4HiJGnvR0RZ1A==/lib/arm64/libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::FunctionWrapper<void (*)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>), facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*, void>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, void (*)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>))+60) (BuildId: 49e1dad0ba9bb0991bf54ebcc3a00d351229d18e)
08-29 02:13:46.129 15060 15060 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 000000000008f924  /data/app/~~UGWiDx2QfyqHzMzDz3yeJA==/com.orderly.ios-8kJ1mW4XV4HiJGnvR0RZ1A==/lib/arm64/libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (reanimated::AndroidScheduler::*)(), &(reanimated::AndroidScheduler::triggerUI()), reanimated::AndroidScheduler, void>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+36) (BuildId: 49e1dad0ba9bb0991bf54ebcc3a00d351229d18e)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue with the following environment in a React-native expo project.

```
//package.json

"react-native": "0.72.4",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
"react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
```

As of today (October 19, 2023) react-native-reanimated latest version is `'3.5.4'`, and updating to that version fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Had the same issue, fixed for me, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

as i cant comment i will add an answer.
What was stated above by @Omal Perera solved my crash.
Ive seen many simular questions but:

`npm install react-native-reanimated @latest`

installed package 3.5.4. Expo-doctor gives an error on this package but since I did this change the build runs good.

expo-doctor message:

> Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo version:
> react-native-reanimated@3.5.4 - expected version: ~3.3.0

ignore this and continue.