# Crash in Expo React Native Android App Involving libreanimated.so and Other Native Libraries, I built it using EAS Online

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, expo, crash

I'm developing an Android app using React Native and have encountered repeated crashes on some devices. The crash logs point to issues with several native libraries, including libreanimated.so, libhermes.so, libhermes_executor.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libexpo-modules-core.so, and libreactnativejni.so. The app crashes sporadically, making it hard to pinpoint the exact cause. Here's a snippet of the log:

```
11-21 10:01:22.136 15463 15463 V SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /data/data/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp/lib-main
11-21 10:01:22.136 15463 15463 D SoLoader: libhermes.so found on /data/app/~~xk_evwS2riSFrK9HIAOIvw==/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp-PBVOBKt8vCGqL-KtciKGsg==/lib/arm64
11-21 10:01:22.138 15463 15463 V SoLoader: libhermes_executor.so not found on /data/data/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp/lib-main
11-21 10:01:22.138 15463 15463 D SoLoader: libhermes_executor.so found on /data/app/~~xk_evwS2riSFrK9HIAOIvw==/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp-PBVOBKt8vCGqL-KtciKGsg==/lib/arm64
11-21 10:01:22.152  2279  6453 D OplusAppListInterceptManager: shouldFilterTask::packageName = com.ibefehdi.jirounapp
11-21 10:01:22.155  2279  2393 D OplusUIFirst_FB: com.ibefehdi.jirounapp moveToTop:[]
11-21 10:01:22.155  2279  2393 D OplusUIFirst_FB: com.ibefehdi.jirounapp boost hint: 15463
11-21 10:01:22.155  2279  2393 D OplusUIFirst_FB: handleParaSwitch com.ibefehdi.jirounapp null null 0
11-21 10:01:22.162 15463 16710 V SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /data/data/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp/lib-main
11-21 10:01:22.162 15463 16710 D SoLoader: libfbjni.so found on /data/app/~~xk_evwS2riSFrK9HIAOIvw==/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp-PBVOBKt8vCGqL-KtciKGsg==/lib/arm64
11-21 10:01:22.174 15463 16710 V SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp/lib-main
11-21 10:01:22.174 15463 16710 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/~~xk_evwS2riSFrK9HIAOIvw==/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp-PBVOBKt8vCGqL-KtciKGsg==/lib/arm64
11-21 10:01:22.217  1436  1571 I SurfaceFlinger: [SF client] NEW(0xb4000079bac68980) for (15463:com.ibefehdi.jirounapp)
11-21 10:01:22.219 15463 15463 D WindowManager: Add to mViews: DecorView@459f7db[MainActivity],pkg= com.ibefehdi.jirounapp
11-21 10:01:22.225  2279  6453 D OplusFullScreenDisplayManager: adjustWindowParamsLw com.ibefehdi.jirounapp, no change cutoutMode: 0
11-21 10:01:22.227  2279  6453 I WindowManager: addWindow: New client android.os.BinderProxy@f9ed2cb : window=Window{edbcaa8 u0 com.ibefehdi.jirounapp/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp.MainActivity}
11-21 10:01:22.229  2279  5872 D CoreBackPreview: Window{edbcaa8 u0 com.ibefehdi.jirounapp/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp.MainActivity}: Setting back callback OnBackInvokedCallbackInfo{mCallback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@23b4566, mPriority=0}
11-21 10:01:22.230 15463 15463 I Quality : Skipped: false 2 cost 23.564585 refreshRate 11142981 bit true processName com.ibefehdi.jirounapp
11-21 10:01:22.253 15463 15463 V SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /data/data/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp/lib-main
11-21 10:01:22.253 15463 15463 D SoLoader: libyoga.so found on /data/app/~~xk_evwS2riSFrK9HIAOIvw==/com.ibefehdi.jirounapp-PBVOBKt8vCGqL-KtciKGsg==/lib/arm64
11-21 10:01:22.257  2279  6453 D OplusFullScreenDisplayManager: adjustWindowParamsLw com.ibefehdi.jirounapp, no change cutoutMode: 0
```

The crashes seem to occur during or after the app's launch, but there's no clear pattern or specific user action that triggers them. I've checked for common issues like memory leaks or improper usage of the mentioned libraries, but haven't found anything conclusive.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with these libraries in a React Native Android app? Any insights on how to debug this or what might be causing these crashes would be greatly appreciated.

I removed the react-native-reanimated library by using
`npm uninstall react-native-reanimated`
but after i created the APK again it was showing the same errors

Comment: I think this is related to your native config when added re-animated. The real problem here is the Soloader can not find and load the native code of the native modules.

So, maybe re-check carefully your native implementation of the native config flows document would help.

Comment: Do you run expo in expo-go or on Expo dev CLI?

Comment: Interesting, I have the same issue 
if I delete
```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
```
the app starts. tried maybe 20 different recomendations from the Internet, nothing helps

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, found that the version that expo required of react-native-reanimated was causing problems. I changed the version from '~3.03' to "3.5.4" in the package.json. I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321237/14759055), credit to [Omal Perera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744975/omal-perera) for this fix.